# Are there any hints for getting Gold Skulltulas on hard?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

In Legend Mode, there are Gold Skulltulas you can only get on hard. Doing a little bit of research online, they only appear when you meet certain objectives, which are different for each level. I can't find any hints about these objectives in the game, though.

Does Hyrule Warriors give any hints about where to find hard difficulty Gold Skulltulas? If so, where can I find these hints? If the game doesn't give direct hints, are there any subtle clues I should I look out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the objectives for finding Gold Skulltulas are available in game! When you are in a mission you can go to warrior info and check the skulltula (see below). The early game skulltulas all require 1000 kills, and can be done with any character. Later ones can have more specific requirements.

If you didn't notice the minimap will have a web with general area the skulltula could be (see below). Additionally, although skultulas will only appear for a limited time, the will always appear in the same location, so when replaying you can narrow down your search area. When you are getting close to a skulltula it will make noise that gets louder as you close in, learn to watch out for this!

Some skulltulas may not be accessible when you first play a level, such as being on ledges which require the hookshot to access.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]